# JQueryMobile and .NET Update Panel Losing Styles

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile, webforms

I am working on a .Net WebForms project and am using UpdatePanels in order to update some information on the page without doing a full post back and losing all the history from the web app (I'm letting JQM manage the history with its back button).

While I have gotten the UpdatePanel to work and display the information I want to, the elements lose their styling. For example, in one form I have a dropdown that updates the list of prices, but when the prices update the dropdown loses its JQM styling.

I have seen various solutions which recommend doing something like this:

```
$('#updateTable').load(function() {
     $(this).trigger('create');
});
```

Unfortunately this does not work. The styling is not applied to the dropdown. However, if I simply call `$('updateTable').trigger('create');` from the console the styling is applied again. I have tried binding to load and ready but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe for the endRequest event on the PageRequestManager and apply the styling there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx

Basically:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args){
    $('#updateTable')... //apply the styles here
}
```